# CiviCRM Campaign - Personal Campaigns

Tags: civicampaign

We have the Campaign (and Personal Campaign Page) option appearing within Contributions and I believe it is impacting on automatic receipting to supporters.   Does anyone know where or how to delete this campaign extension.

Comment: Is it showing up online or in emails receipts?

Comment: Neither.  It appears in CiviCRM under Contributions and the automatic email receipts are not being generated.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots?

Comment: I cannot seem to add the screenshots unfortunately.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the screen shot or you can email me at pradpnayak at gmail dot com

Answer (score 1):

CiviCampaign is not an extension but a component (ie it's part of the core), you can enable/disable it from (administer>system settings>Components)

and disable it.

This being said, I'd be surprised it's the issue, lots of install have civicampaign enabled and working email receipts

Comment: Thanks, I have now disabled it.  Hopefully there will be no further auto email receipt issues.